# How to reduce the frequency of such errors in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKbah/):

```
var requests = [
  $.ajax("http://search.twitter.com/search.json", { data: { q: 'ashishnjain' }, dataType: 'jsonp' })
    .done(function() {console.log("request");}),

  $.ajax("http://search.twitter.com/search.json", { data: { q: 'ashishnjain' }, dataType: 'jsonp' })
    .done(function() {console.log("request");})
];

$.when(requests).done(console.log("alldone"));
```

The expected output is: `request request alldone`, but in reality this prints `alldone request request`.

There are actually two bugs in this code (left as an exercise if you enjoy that kind of thing), but ultimately I think this occurs because JavaScript and jQuery are both extremely lenient when given arguments that make no sense whatsoever. In this environment, the "right" thing seems to be "do something or nothing, just do not throw an error!".

Seeing as this code **passes JsLint**, and has just cost me a couple of hours to debug (the real code was of course a few orders of magnitude more complex), I'm wondering what else I can do to reduce wasting time on such unwarranted leniency. This isn't an isolated example; it seems to happen over and over again. Any suggestions?

Comment: The arguments make no sense according to you. According to the engine, I'm sure they do. Which errors would you expect from your "bugs"? Something like "invalid argument"?

Comment: @bzlm I'd love to discuss that, but I fear this will pull the question off track. I can't change JavaScript, and I can't change jQuery (much), so I'm wondering how to avoid things like this.

Comment: I feel your pain. It is incredible how popular this error-prone style of programming is. Hardly a day passes without me having to trawl through my own JS code and stare at every detail of the subtlest of syntaxes, to find errors which a proper compiler would find and flag in a fraction of a second. I don’t know how other people enjoy this frustrating experience, but however they do it, they can’t be very productive that way.

Comment: @Timwi: A static type system limits many of the nice things you want to do. A good type system will be more flexible but I'd rather have an untiped language than limit submit myself to Java for example.

Comment: @missingno: If you are interested in a reasoned, civilised debate about the pros and cons of dynamic vs. static typing, we could have one on Skype if you like (my userid: timwiterby).

Answer (score 3):

It's is actually possible to [check types](http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/) in runtime in Javascript, it's just that being strict is not the preferred style in Javascript. JS hackers like to hang it loose.

Other hackers cope with this though, right? So, rather than blaming the language or jQuery for your long hours spend debugging this problem, I would suggest instead investigating other ways to reduce your debugging efforts.

Here are a couple of suggestions I can think of:

1. Test out small pieces of code in the interactive JS console first before pasting it in your .js file: this

   - allows you to rapidly iterate until you get it right(how do you use $.when() ?)
   - ensures that when you do get it right, you understand how to use the API
2. Keep studying JS, and keep writing more of it. The second error you made: not wrapping console.log("all done") in a function shows that a fundamental concept about JS has not fully locked into place yet - a seasoned JS hacker would never make that mistake.

Comment: `“a seasoned JS hacker would never make that mistake”` — how sure are you of this? You can say this only because we can’t look at your screen all the time. If anyone saw you make a similar mistake in JS, even once, you’d look like a big hypocrite.

Comment: Type checking will only protect against type errors. OP's mistake is not actually a type error (and more an issue of $.when having a cluttered API)

Comment: OP's mistake *is* actually a type error (at least, the one about not wrapping `console.log` would be revealed by type-checking).  I'm a seasoned JS hacker and I make that mistake about once every two weeks.

Comment: @missingno: Both of the OP’s mistakes are clearly type errors and would have been caught by a type-checking compiler.

Comment: I still hold that these are actually API design errors that no ammount of type checking would fix. The unwraped console.log() should trigger a runtime exception (trying to call a non-callable) but the lib purposedly put a check there to silently ignore this error. A static type system might make these less likely (by *encouraging* a less promiscuous API design - having done accept a null success callback is arguably a mistake just as having when be both a deferred-creator and a list-of-deferred synchronizer) but a type checker wouldn't prevent these errors given this same API

Comment: @missingno: I’m afraid you are wrong. In a properly typed environment, `done` would be declared to take a *function* as a parameter. If your argument expression is not of type *function*, it’s a type error. The fact that the value happens to be `null` at runtime is completely irrelevant at compile-time.

Comment: If the function accepts NULL then it isn't protecting you against the unwraped console.log error.

Comment: @missingno: What is your point? In a properly typed environment, it wouldn’t need to protect against this error because *the compiler would already catch it and never permit the function to be called in this way.*

Comment: @Timwi: You are right, just emembered NULL comes in many flavours duh. It is still annoying that there is an explicit check that silently allows the silly .done(NULL) though.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your more prominent error, the answer can be said in two words: [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing).  Static typing doesn't solve every problem but it tears a big chunk out of the work involved in tracking down these subtle failures.

The downsides of static types are *not*, as missingno claims, anything to do with making programming more difficult or less powerful or anything like that.  The biggest problem is that strength of a language's typing system seems to vary inversely with the popularity of the language.  Very well typed typed languages like Scala and Haskell are still at the boutique level of acceptance.  Java is much more popular, but its type-system is difficult to use and shot full of holes; something similar can be said of C#.  The type system of the immensely popular PHP would strike a neutral observer as a deliberate sabotage.  Older languages like FORTAN and C don't even try.

I don't know why this is, but I am convinced that the obvious explanation -- people don't like strong typing -- is not correct.

A related problem is that you cannot yet compile any strongly-typed language down to JavaScript.  The closest approach is probably [GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit).

Comment: The undecideability of the halting-problem guarantees that there are well behaved untyped programs that cannot be checked statically by a compiler so it technically static types are a limitation :P But yes, I think you are correct in identifying that Haskell has made me too picky when it comes to type systems.

Comment: @missingno: This has nothing to do with the halting problem. You don’t need a Turing-complete type system to express any program. If you need relaxed type checking, you can always use the uber-type `object`. On top of that, C# even has the `dynamic` type which is a lot like what you want. With this, static typing is an additional feature on top of what an untyped language can provide, and doesn’t take anything away. (In practice, I find the `dynamic` type to be very rarely useful.)

Comment: @Timwi: I had hoped the silly smiley face would have made clear that that was an obviously over-the-top remark.

Comment: @missingno -- It was clear to me.  But your point is well-taken: there are certainly errors that static-typing cannot possibly catch.  The halting problem is one, but mostly there are specification problems.  A statically type-correct program will definitely do *something* (except maybe halt) and probably something sensible but how do you know it will do the thing you want?

Comment: @Malvolio: What point is well-taken? How does pointing out that static typing isn’t perfect argue for dynamic typing, which is even worse?

Comment: @Timwi: It can't be *strictly* better if there are things that you can only do with a dynamic system. No static type system covers can cover all the bases so there is always something, like generic-function-apply, the Y-combinator or duck-typing, that you are prevented from doing (or will have to go through an workaround to do). In principle, choosing a dynamic type system is a *tradeof* between safety and the ability to do things that might not have been considered when the language was designed in the first place.

Comment: @missingno -- I am not convinced that static typing *isn't* strictly better than dynamic, that there's anything that you can only do with a dynamic system.  Look at Scala and Haskell: they make convincing evidence that dynamic typing is never required.  (I could be talked out of it though, if you want to take this to a discussion thread)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mistook

```
$.when([x,y])
```

for

```
$.when(x,y)
```

I don't think there is an analysis tool out there that will help catch this kind of mistake since it is perfectly acceptable to pass a list to when. If you want to have a more restrictive function you can make one yourself:

```
function whenForMoreThanOne(list_of_deferreds){
    return $.when.apply($, list_of_deferreds);
}
```